# j2me, generate random location of food for simple snake game

Tags: java-me

here is my code for the snake game, the thing i need to do is generate location for          the snake food, once the snake touch the snake food, it will regenerate the location of the food~pls, i really need your guys help!!! just kindly have a look

```
package snake;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Canvas;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Graphics;


public class SnakeCanvas extends Canvas{

private int currentX =getWidth()/2;
private int currentY =getHeight()/2;
private boolean condition = false;
private boolean position = false;
Random rand = new Random();
int randomX=rand.nextInt(180) + 20;
int randomY =rand.nextInt(250) + 20;


private final Midlet midlet;
private int score = 0;

Timer t;

public SnakeCanvas(Midlet midlet)
{


this.midlet = midlet;

t = new Timer();
 t.schedule(new TimerTask() {

public void run() {


if((condition==false)&&(position==false))
{
currentY -= 5 ;
}
if((condition==false)&&(position==true))
{
 currentY += 5 ;
}
if((condition==true)&&(position==false))
{
currentX -= 5 ;
}
if((condition==true)&&(position==true))
{
currentX += 5 ;
}
}
}, 50, 50);
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
boolean touch=false;
//drawing Background
g.setColor(0x000000);
g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
//drawing snake

g.setColor(0xffffff);
g.fillRoundRect(currentX, currentY, 20, 20, 5, 5);

 //snake food


   g.setColor(234,41,42);
   g.fillRect(randomX,randomY,10,10);
  if((currentX-9<=randomX+4&&currentX+9>=randomX-4)&&(currentY-9<=randomY+4&&currentY+9>=randomY-4)){

    addScore();
   }
 //drawing block
  g.setColor(82,133,190);
  g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), 5);
  g.fillRect(0, getHeight()-5, getWidth(), 5);
  g.fillRect(0, 0, 5, getHeight());
  g.fillRect(getWidth()-5, 0, 5, getHeight());
 if((currentX>=getWidth()-10)||(currentX<5)||(currentY>=getHeight()-5)||(currentY<5))
 midlet.GameOver();
 g.setColor(142,255,17);
 g.drawString("Score : "+score, 8, 7, Graphics.TOP|Graphics.LEFT);
 repaint();

 }

  protected void keyPressed(int keyCode) {
  System.out.println(keyCode);
  switch(keyCode)
 {
case -1:
condition = false;
position = false;
break;
case -2:
condition = false;
position = true;
break;

case -3:
condition = true;
position = false;
break;

case -4:
condition = true;
position= true;
break;
}
repaint();
}

private void addScore() {
    score=score+1;**strong text**

}
private void food(){
Random rand = new Random();
int randomX=rand.nextInt(150) + 20;
int randomY=rand.nextInt(250) + 20;
}

}
```

Comment: What and Where is your problem? Also,please remove all the irrelevent code and post a short code containing only the relevent code

Comment: sry, i m newbie here, my problem actually is on the //snakefood of public void paint(graphic g), how do i regenerate a random location of snake food once the snake is touch the snake food~ *with the Random rand = new Random();
int randomX=rand.nextInt(180) + 20;
int randomY =rand.nextInt(250) + 20;

Answer (score 0):

Okay. I don't know if you managed to solve your problem but there seems to be a couple things wrong with your code.

First in this code block in the beginning:

```
Private int currentX =getWidth()/2;
private int currentY =getHeight()/2;
private boolean condition = false;
private boolean position = false;
Random rand = new Random();
int randomX=rand.nextInt(180) + 20;
int randomY =rand.nextInt(250) + 20;
```

^I am sure this does not compile, you can't have function calls when declaring header variables.

Second

```
if((condition==false)&&(position==false))
{
currentY -= 5 ;
}
if((condition==false)&&(position==true))
{
 currentY += 5 ;
}
if((condition==true)&&(position==false))
{
currentX -= 5 ;
}
if((condition==true)&&(position==true))
{
currentX += 5 ;
}
}
}, 50, 50);
}
```

Your block coding style is horrible and hard to read. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_style#Indentation has a good guide on mastering this, read it!
This applies to your switch/case statements too!

Lastly your question:

```
private void food(){
Random rand = new Random();
int randomX=rand.nextInt(150) + 20;
int randomY=rand.nextInt(250) + 20;
}
```

^ Just generates random numbers, but doesn't do anything with them. I am guessing you meant:

```
private void food(){
Random rand = new Random();
randomX=rand.nextInt(150) + 20;
randomY=rand.nextInt(250) + 20;
}
```

which sets the classes global randomX and randomY to new values.

This doesn't help though since you don't actually call the Food() function anywhere in this class! And considering it is "Private" and can only be used by this class that must be an error.

tl;dr You need to study programming some more, but it is a good effort. I will help you more in the comments if you like. If my answer helped, please accept it.

Fenix